# Defining arrays by a loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have data in many arrays

```
$verbs_L1_occurr, 
$verbs_L2_occurr, 
$verbs_L3_occurr, 
.....)
```

and
based on them I define new arrays removing all double values:

```
$verbs_L1_unique = array_unique($verbs_L1_occurr);  
$verbs_L2_unique = array_unique($verbs_L2_occurr);
$verbs_L3_unique = array_unique($verbs_L3_occurr);
etc.
```

My whole code including this snippet works perfectly fine and being a beginner 
I am insanely proud of it, but I find it disturbing to have so many repeating lines. 
I suspect any experienced programmer
would have a good laugh here...

Question therefore: **how can I simplify this?** Whichever way I tried to loop through 
this, I don't get it right. Tried a counter to loop through, but whatever
 I do I get an error or 'invalid argument'.
Am very grateful for any hint, thank you!

Comment: Anytime you have a number of variables named the same except for a number at the end (or in this, a number in the middle) an array could be used to simplify everything. So you can create an array called `$verbs` that is an array of arrays. Then loop through this efficiently without duplicating too much code.

Comment: If you don't need to keep both the arrays with all values and unique values, then just re-use the same variables for the unique. And if you wanted to just not worry about the unique, depending on the content of the original array, you can make an associative array so that when there is a duplicate you end up overwriting the value instead of adding a duplicate. Without more code, it is hard to tell what you are doing. But either way, this is likely off topic for SO. SO is for fixing code, but however ugly, this code works. There is a codereview.stackexchange.com that might be better.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code you wrote where you tried loops in which you encountered errors, so we could help debug where you went wrong specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You have several solutions.

### 1 - Call dynamically the variable

On a loop, I will create a variable with the name of the variable and call it dnamically by a double $$.
I don't like this solution :)

```
<?php
$verbs_L1_occurr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
$verbs_L2_occurr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'];

for( $i = 1 ; $i < 2 ; $i++ ) { // iterate from 1 to 2
  $function = 'verbs_L' . $i . '_occcur';
  $$function = array_unique($$function);
}
```

### 2 - Use 3D arrays

(As said by Scott)

```
<?php // I use php 5.4
$verbs = [];
$verbs['L1'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
$verbs['L2'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'];

foreach( $verbs as $key => $values )
  $verbs[$key] = array_unique($values);
```

or just:

```
$verbs = array_map('array_unique', $verbs);
```